# Benchmarking the CPU calculation power

Tags: java, android, math, benchmarking, computation

I am trying to benchmark CPU calculation power with a simple function, without adding huge frameworks with thousands of lines and some MB's to my project.

I developed this sample code. It is a for which does 100 times a huge task. This huge task (benchmark() function) consists in a while which will do a math complex calc and increasing a counter in a period of 100ms. Each 100ms it is printed in log the number of times that the benchmark() function has completed the complex math calculation.

OK, so, I have 100 times printed on screen that calculation.

The first times I execute the benchmark I get correct results, more or less the same log results for each one of the 100 iterations of the benchmark:

```
08-18 13:09:52.806 26543-27748/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 0 Result: 118200
08-18 13:09:52.906 26543-27748/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 1 Result: 171580
08-18 13:09:53.006 26543-27748/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 2 Result: 170654
08-18 13:09:53.106 26543-27748/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 3 Result: 168676
08-18 13:09:53.206 26543-27748/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 4 Result: 168372
08-18 13:09:53.306 26543-27748/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 5 Result: 165558
08-18 13:09:53.406 26543-27748/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 6 Result: 171368
08-18 13:09:53.506 26543-27748/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 7 Result: 171680
08-18 13:09:53.606 26543-27748/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 8 Result: 171516
08-18 13:09:53.706 26543-27748/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 9 Result: 171598
```

But after some executions the number starts decreasing, and I don't understand why:

```
08-18 13:10:20.850 26543-28161/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 1 Result: 94320
08-18 13:10:20.951 26543-28161/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 2 Result: 90364
08-18 13:10:21.051 26543-28161/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 3 Result: 94240
08-18 13:10:21.152 26543-28161/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 4 Result: 93676
08-18 13:10:21.252 26543-28161/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 5 Result: 91554
08-18 13:10:21.352 26543-28161/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 6 Result: 94358
08-18 13:10:21.452 26543-28161/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 7 Result: 90954
08-18 13:10:21.552 26543-28161/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 8 Result: 94874
08-18 13:10:21.652 26543-28161/com.mytestapp D/XXXX: Iteration: 9 Result: 94464
```

If I wait some minutes and try again, the results increases again to its normal values.

Why this behaviour? How to avoid it and get always correct benchmark results?

This is my sample code:

```
public void benchmarkIterator(){
    int result = 0;
    int iterations = 100;
    for (int i=0; i<iterations; i++){
       result = benchmark();
       Log.d("XXXX", "Iteration: "+i+" Result: "+result);
    }
}
```

....

```
     public int benchmark(){
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int count=0;
        double aux=0;
        while((System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)<100){
            count++;
            double d = 7777777777d;
            aux = 0;
            aux=aux+(int)(aux+Math.sin(d)*Math.cos(d));
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: just confirming my conclusion, a bigger result means a faster CPU right? i mean more math ops was made in that 100 MS? could it be some optimization or JIT stuff?

Comment: the higher result, the fastest math calculation has this cpu

Comment: Coult it be overheating and some kind of thermal throtling?

Answer (score 1):

Overheating?  No.  I doubt that this calculation can make your CPU break a sweat.

I think the change over time has to do with the JVM and statistics.  The HotSpot compiler uses them to optimize code branching based on what your code is doing.

http://blog.takipi.com/jvm-performance-magic-tricks/

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PerformanceTechniques

The only way you can know what's happening is to use a profiler.  You need to look at garbage collection, memory, and where the time is being spent.  Your simple benchmark won't give you that kind of insight.

Comment: duffymo please, can you give me some help with how to solve this? can't find the way to solve it with your links. Thank you so much

Comment: I don't think you have a problem to solve.  I'm pointing out that this is the way the JVM works.  The time will improve as you run more cases to an asymptotic value.  If you restart the app it'll have to "warm up" and accumulate a new statistical branching model.  It's one reason why micro-benchmarks can be deceiving.

Comment: so duffymo , the solution whould be to execute 1000 iterations and listen only for the result of the last 500?

Comment: Yes, some people recommend a "warm up" period for the JVM.  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-benchmarking-2266277.html

Comment: but then, why decreases it's results instead of increasing them?

Comment: Don't know.  What's happening to memory?  Garbage collection?  Threads?  You can't answer this without a profiler and lots more insight into what your code is really doing.

Comment: Yes all what dujjymo says : do a few before u start measuring. make sure no other apps doing background activity. keep it running even when number falls and see it comes back to higher numbers on its own (GC pause), are you sure each piece of work is not increasing memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the two log snippet are for different execution made with different JVM launches?

In this case, the difference between the two cannot be caused by the JVM (as it has been restarted).

So, the difference can be caused by a lot of stuff: OS file cache (there is already some file stuff going on), CPU power management (CPU frequency going down when not in used can take some times to go back to it's max frequency), something else running on the host (if it's a VM ... a lot of stuff can going on), CPU optimization (like branch prediction of prefetching), ...

Anyway, you don't have an issue, it's just the way computer/jvm/cpu  works these days ...

Comment: wtf, then how to make a benchmark for android/java?? also it is in the same execution of the aplication, i press the bench button a few times to make these tests

Comment: if it's on the same JVM launch, it's can be the JVM internal optimization thats kick in and out. It's complexe but some optimization is done by the JVM (the Hotspot/JIT) and if you don't use some part of the code there can also be some de-optimization. Benchmarking is really hard and this kind of micro-benchmarking needs to be done with a benchamrking harness to avoid JVM/OS optimisation and not in your application. Check JMH : http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/